# Show that a set of vectors is a basis in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Can you please explain this question to me?

> Show that the vectors $\beta = \{(1,1,0,0), (0,1,1,0), (0,0,1,1), (1,0,0,1)\}$ are basis in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Attempt:

The set is a basis if the vectors are linearly independent. But when I solved the question, the vectors were linearly *dependent*. But the questions says "show that ..." which means that the vectors form a basis. I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Are you sue that this is word for word what the question asked? Because (A) you are right that this set is _not_ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$, and (B) it's not correct English to say "...are basis...". So maybe the original statement has been mistranscribed?

Answer (score 3):

The vectors are **linearly dependent**.  To see why, consider that if $a_{1} = (1,1,0,0)$, $a_{2} = (0,1,1,0)$ and $a_{3} = (0,0,1,1)$ and $a_{4} = (1,0,0,1)$, then $a_{4}$ can be written as $a_{1} - a_{2} + a_{3}$.

Comment: so what will be the basis of the set?  because the question says that " show that the set is a basis in $R^4$".

Comment: A basis of the set $\beta := \{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}\}$ is the set $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3} \}$.  Note that this isn't a basis of $\Bbb R^{4}$ since a basis of $\Bbb R^{4}$ must have 4 elements.

Comment: @user46944 More precisely, $\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ is a basis for the **vector space** spanned by the original set.  That set of four vectors is not a vector space and hence cannot have a basis.

Comment: @ErickWong good point. I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible methods is to calculate a determinant for the matrix constructed from vectors  $(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0),(0,0,1,1),(1,0,0,1)$. Because it has many $0$'s it is easy to calculate it by hand or with the use of [matrix calculator](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx).
We see that the matrix has zero determinant so the vectors are linearly dependent and can't be a basis.

Answer (score 0):

If $w, x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^4$, all that needs to be checked is whether or not they are all linearly independent.

Suppose that $w, x, y, z$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but somehow do not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. This contradicts the fundamental theorem of linear algebra by the fact that $dim(\mathbb{R}^n) = n$

The easiest method is to represent your vectors as column vectors in a matrix $A$, and then row reduce to see if they are linearly independent.